# Why is a function with a required parameter assignable to a function type where the parameter is optional

Tags: typescript, callback, optional-parameters, type-safety

#### Question

Simply put, I wonder why the following is valid:

```
type Func = (param?: string) => void;

const func: Func = (param: string) => {
  return;
};
```

#### The problem

In practice, this becomes a problem for callbacks, where the callback function may be invoked with one or no parameter, but the provided callback may just assume a parameter is provided, causing `cannot read property of undefined` errors.

Is there another type safe way to approach callbacks which may or may not be called with parameters?

#### Solution

`strictNullChecks` *and* `strictFunctionTypes` are required to invalidate the code example. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction [Vlaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz)!

Comment: "*I wonder why the following is valid:*" [it isn't](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQBRgIYCdsC2A-AFxQDOwuAlggOYCUaAfFAG4D21AJgNwCwAKCFIOCSlABmiJGXjI0mHPgJlKNek1SsA3kKhRcEYHFwIBggL68gA). Do you have the `strictNullChecks` compiler option enabled?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Yes I have!

Comment: Then this shouldn't be valid with `strictNullChecks` as I've shown in the playground above. It will only be valid code with `strictNullChecks` disabled: [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&strictNullChecks=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQBRgIYCdsC2A-AFxQDOwuAlggOYCUaAfFAG4D21AJgNwCwAKCFIOCSlABmiJGXjI0mHPgJlKNek1SsA3kKhRcEYHFwIBggL68gA). The issue you describe cannot happen with the configuration you describe.

Comment: Well, `strictNullChecks` in my code catches errors like: `const users = [{ name: 'Oby', age: 12 }, { name: 'Heera', age: 32 }]; const loggedInUser = users.find(u => u.name === ''); loggedInUser.name;`. If I disable `stictNullChecks`, the code above would be allowed. It isn't. I guess I must do something wrong in the config. Thanks for pointing that out, but I can for a fact see that `strictNullChecks` checks for certain types of errors in my code.

Comment: It's the option that directly affects it: [screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0gzW.gif).

Comment: You still ignore that your proposed solution isn't the whole solution to my problem, which is frankly a bit annoying. Besides that, thank you a lot for pointing me in the right direction! Apparently, `strictNullChecks` combined with `strictFunctionTypes` is required. 

Again, thank you for your time and have a nice day!